# Assign random numbers to a column with NULL values in mySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table named `employees` and a column named  `group`. Now, upon checking the table, the column has `NULL` values and I want to assign them a proper numbers from 1 to 10. Can anyone help me on this one? I don't know where to start, please note that i want to update the values that are `NULL` only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this update:

```
UPDATE employees
SET `group` = FLOOR( 1 + RAND( ) *10 )
WHERE `group` IS NULL;
```

As a side note, `GROUP` is a MySQL reserved keyword, and you should avoid naming your columns etc. using it.

Comment: Thanks for this, yeah, my actual column name is `group_id`. Thanks for the reminders anyway :)